# ContainsIgnoreCase in JSP

Tags: jsp

Hi I want to search for a word in a given string in jsp and I am using string.contains(). But it is case sensitive and I want to ignore case.
I have tried  string.containsIgnoreCase("") but it is showing an error. Is there any other way?
I searched and found this code to use

```
<c:set var="theString" value="I am a test String"/><c:if test="${fn:containsIgnoreCase(theString, 'test')}"> <p>Found test string<p>
```

But its not working. Can I get other ways?

Comment: please post your code.
and also add what error that you are getting.

Comment: What error are you getting with this?

Comment: Am using netbeans and it is shoe\wing redline for compareIgnoreCase and i came to know why. But for the second code it is not showing an error but it is not working. The word is not detected.

Comment: Is this the full code you are using or is there anything else in that?

Comment: You dont have to make those conversions to upper or lower case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BTW we are talking about jstl functions tag. It has containsIgnoreCase function.
Expecting that your jsp has jstl tag references:

```
    <%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
    <%@taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
        .....
    <c:set var="theString" value="I am a test String"/>
    <c:if test="${fn:containsIgnoreCase(theString, 'test')}"><p>Found test string</p></c:if>
```

You need to close the p and c:if tags.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is. change both string to lower case using `toLowerCase()` & then simply compare using `equals()` or `contains()` method[if you want to check contains or not].

& by the way its `compareToIgnoreCase()` there is nothing like `containsIgnoreCase()` method in java.lang.String.